# How do you hide UV seams?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I made a simple low poly rock and want to do the textures with blender and export everything to UE4. However, when I apply a texture to my rock the UV seam is very obvious. I have tried using the clone tool in texture paint mode to hide the seam but it doesn't help. Is there a way to hide the seam?

Comment: You probably need to extend UV edge bleeding to avoid that problem. Can you add a snapshot of the UV/Image Editor with the texture?

Comment: I'll try to add a screenshot soon when I'm back at my computer. It's not seams coming from texture painting its a seam from where I UV unwrapped and the texture is a rock texture that is different colors where the seam is.

Comment: You might want to make that texture tileable so the seams won't be seen. You can do that either by yourself using Stamp tool in the image editor or using image editor filters.

Comment: Could you please upload some screenshots or put the .blend file on [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the given link in your question.

Comment: "I have tried using the clone tool in texture paint mode to hide the
seam but it doesn't help". Just curious, have you saved the modified texture after the modifications? Blender does not do this for you. I was trapped by this also a few times before. Painted the seams away in Blender, forgot to save the modified texture, and wondered why the seams were visible in Unity then ^^

Answer (score 1):

Select your rock, in edit mode clear all seams, mark another set of seams different from the previous set, create a new UV map (name it "target"), unwrap the mesh, in the image editor create a new blank image and save it to the HD.

Go to the render tab, Bake tab: Bake Textures.
This procedure creates a 2D image - with visible seams - that can be doctored with a 2D image editor and then used as texture with the "target" UV map.
Make sure not to touch the borders of your new image while doctoring, or you'll create new visible seams.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend partly on what kind of rocks you are wanting to texture, and how you anticipate those rocks being used in the game. On the one hand, if you want large rocks with sharp edges, such as some of those that you can see used as "rip rap" at [(33.607470, -97.953118)](https://goo.gl/maps/Ju7UejDTpPy) [Zoom way in, or go to street view] , I've had some preliminary success modeling these, applying a procedural texture, and then making my own image textures from screen shots or the originals. In these cases the seams fit neatly along the sharper edges of the boulders.

In my experience, there are some mesh-texture combinations where there is no possible unwrapping of a mesh to a texture that avoids an unwrapping of the mesh to the texture in a way that does not produce an ugly and unsatisfying seam. In these cases, I've take refuge in the old marketing adage, "If you can't hide it, make it a feature." What I do in those cases where there is no satisfactory place for a seam, is to intentionally make the item, in this case, the rock, of two different (real world) materials, so that there has to be a seam. Consider the four rocks pictured in this collage:

[image: collage]

Each is composed of more than one material, or at least, is composed of several visible layers of the same material, and affords convenient places to hide a seam.